# Activation/deactivation of a form at the result of a dropdown selection

Tags: php, yii2

I have the following codes:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'parent_id')->dropDownList($categories, ['class' => 'select']) ?>                                              
<?= $form->field($model, "[{$lang['id']}]anchors",['template' => $template])->textarea(['class' => 'form-control editor']);?>
```

The first line is the dropdown list with multiple choices. Among the dropdown choices there is an option(`$model->parent_id ==10`) which I would like to make it in a way that, when a user selects that option the second line to be inactive or hidden.
I tried to solve it with jquery but it didn't work.

Please share with me your solutions on this issue

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'parent_id')->dropDownList($categories, ['id' => 'myParentField', 'prompt' => '--- Select Parent ---']) ?>  

<div id="showField" style="display:none">                                            
    <?= $form->field($model, "[{$lang['id']}]anchors",['template' => $template])->textarea(['class' => 'form-control editor']);?>
</div>
```

Register Js in Your Form like below

```
<?php
$this->registerJs(<<<JS
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myParentField').on('change', function() {
         if (($('#myParentField').val()) == '10') {
            $("#showField").show();
         } else {
            $("#showField").hide();
         }
      });
   });
JS
);
?>
```

Refer [Working with Client Scripts (Yii2 Register Js)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html)

Comment: @Rasim Aghayev Your issue is resolve or not ? If my answer is help full then mark as accept. because this answer is help to another one.

Comment: vishub, thank you very much for your solution. Yes it was helpful. Only this morning I had a chance to see your solution that is why it took a day to accept the answer.

Comment: @RasimAghayev Most Welcome